# Roots of unity in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-2})$.

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-2})$. I already showed that the ring of integers in $K$ is $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2},\sqrt{-2})$ and the discriminant is $1600$.

Now the goal is to show that the roots of unity in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ are $\pm1$:
We know $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, $K$ is Galois with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and that the only quadratic subfields are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2}),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-10})$.

$K$ is not cyclotomic because there is no cyclotomic field of degree $4$ with discriminant 1600.

From this it follows that any root of unity is contained in a quadratic subfield. In the three quadratic subfields the only roots of unity are $\pm1$.

How would one show that the extension is Galois?
(I assume we show that there are exactly $4$ automorphisms. But what would those be?)

Why exactly does it follow that any root of unity is contained in a quadratic subfield?

Comment: If $\zeta_{p^k}\in K$ then $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^k}):\Bbb{Q}]=p^{k-1}(p-1)$ divides $4$, this implies $p^k\in 2,3,4,5,8$, thus it reduces to show that $\sqrt{-3},i,\zeta_5$ are not in $K$. only $\zeta_5$ is non-obvious, and it follows from that $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\Bbb{Q})$ is cyclic of degree $4$ whereas $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is not.

Comment: What does the notation $\zeta_{p^{k}}$ mean? The $p^{k}$th root of unity?

Comment: Sure ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Isn't it much simpler here to observe that the imaginary part of an element of $\mathcal{O}_K$ belongs to $\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}$, and hence an element can only have absolute value $1$ if it is real?